# I'm trying to establish connection with ms sql via C# win forms app

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

I was looking for information on the internet and all I found is that I should add System.Data.SqlClient in order to work with SQL so I added and nothing seems to work, all lines related with SQL still red and I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Have you added it to the References list in the project too, i.e. include the System.Data.SqlClient assembly not just using the namespace in your code?

Comment: (Note in general we prefer code posted as text not as screenshots, but I think it's OK here: you're showing us the error and the code isn't really relevant.)

Comment: @Rup i think i didn't and it would be great if you tell me how to do that because I'm almost 0 at this topic

Comment: Is this .Net 5 or .Net core in VS Code? I'd try `dotnet add package System.Data.SqlClient` on the command line. I don't know how to do that in the IDE sorry, but it'll be there somewhere.

Comment: If it's .Net Framework in full Visual Studio then right-click References in the project pane and 'Add Reference' then select it from the list.

Comment: @Rup i'll try and then tell you what happened

Comment: @Rup so i managed to find where i should add some reference but what exactly I need to add?
here is the link to what I opened
https://prnt.sc/12mc7sx

Comment: @Rup not sure if it will help but here is what IDE says to me 
https://prnt.sc/12mcpzc

Comment: Yes, that error message is telling you to do the same thing. Have you tried the 'Show potential fixes' link? That might do this for you.

Comment: So this is .NET 5/Core in full VS? Right-click Dependencies, Manage NuGet Packages, Browse, search for System.Data.SqlClient, Install.

Comment: @Rup i tried to allow IDE fix that problem for me but it just suggested to create new class and nothing me/
I don't remember but I think it's .net core and it's visual studio not vs code

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install and use the new System.Data.SqlClient package in NuGet to your project or solution. Follow these steps to install the package:

1. Right Click on your solution from the solution panel in VS.
2. From the context menu, select the Manage NuGet Packages for solutions...
3. In the NuGet Package Manager window, select the Browse Tab.
4. In the search box type in System.Data.SqlClient and press enter.
5. Look for the package System.Data.SqlClient by Microsoft and select it.
6. A small panel will open at the right side of the window with the list of projects in your solution. Select only the projects you want the SqlClient package to be installed.
7. Then press the install button. Wait for the installation to complete. NuGet will install the selected package and all it’s dependencies.
8. Now go back to your solution or project and rebuild. You will not get the error again.
   Here is the link for the full article:
   https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/error-sqlconnection-could-not-be-found